# Is there anyway to find which user contribute to an Anylogic model?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have an Anylogic model to test. There are some problems about the execution of the model. I want to find the person who made some parts of the model to get a right solution from him/her. Is there any way to find, which user made which part? I couldnt find any relative part in the program.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean? You have a model that was done by a team and you want to know who did what code in the model so you go and speak to them directly ? Or you have a resource in your model that works a part (agent) and you want to have an assessment on what did each resource work on?

for the first option:
you can't unless everybody puts their names in the code and descriptions indicating what they changed or if you use a version control tool such as GIT

For the second option:

your question is a bit too broad... but what you can do to verify your model is to use the execution log, which will tell you what resource worked on what parts and for how long.

you turn your execution logs clickin in the database in your projects tab, in the database properties in the log section."Log model execution"

After that you want to check the resource_unit_states_log, which has all the information on what each one of your resources did in details, which answers your question.

There are other ways, but this will be the answer :)